# Displaying digits in forward direction in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that takes an inputted integer and reads the digits forwards. So 12345 would be...

```
Digit: 1
Digit: 2
Digit: 3
Digit: 4
Last Digit: 5
```

Inputs with trailing zeros (like 100000) run into problems though. In the forward direction, some of these zeros show up as 9's and the last integer does not show up as 'Last Digit:'. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int output2 = 0;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Number? > ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    i = n;
    j = n;


    while (i){
        i = i/10;
        count++;
    }


    printf("Foward direction \n");
    while (count > 0){
        k = j;
        k /= pow(10, count - 1);
        output2 = k % 10;
        if (output2 >= pow(10, count - 1)){
            printf("Last digit: %d \n", output2);
        }
        else {
            printf("Digit: %d \n", output2);
        }
        count -= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code works fine even for input `100000` http://ideone.com/XMoH7b

Comment: Probably floating point error on the `pow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be clever, simple and elegant, you can always use recursion.

```
void print_digits(int n)
{
    if (n >= 10) {
        print_digits(n / 10);
    }
    putc('0' + n % 10, stdout);
}
```

In your code, `pow()` is erroneous - don't try to use floating-point numbers to solve problems about integer numbers.

**Edit:** here's the full homework done for OP, just so that @darron will be happy as well:

```
void print_digits(int n, int islast)
{
    if (n >= 10) {
        print_digits(n / 10, 0);
    }

    if (islast) {
        printf("Last ");
    }

    printf("Digit: %d\n", n % 10);
}
```

Call with the `islast` argument initially being true (nonzero):

```
print_digits(12345, 1);
```

this produces

```
Digit: 1
Digit: 2
Digit: 3
Digit: 4
Last Digit: 5
```

as output.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by H2CO3 and Cyan, the `pow` function and/or the division operation lead to the inexact result. It's hard to control rounding errors when using floating-point arithmetic (I for one don't know how), so you should use integers.

Make a function that looks like `pow` but works with integers:

```
int int_pow(int what, int power)
{
    ...
}
```

Or even a function that calculates a power of 10:

```
int pow_of_10(int power)
{
    ...
}
```

Then use it instead of `pow`.

---

Alternatively, calculate the maximal power of 10 in the first loop:

```
while (i){
    i = i/10;
    count++;
    ... // add code here
}
```

Then use it to calculate lesser powers of 10.

Answer (score 1):

I probably missed the context of the question, but this should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct digit
{
    struct digit *next;
    int value;
};

void print_digits(int value)
{
    struct digit *top = malloc(sizeof(*top));
    top->value = value % 10;
    top->next = NULL;
    value /=10;

    while (value)
    {
        struct digit *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        p->value = value % 10;
        p->next = top;
        top = p;
        value /= 10;
    }

    while (top)
    {
        struct digit *p = top;
        top = top->next;
        printf(top ? "Digit: %d\n" : "Last Digit : %d\n", p->value);
        free(p);
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_digits(0);
    print_digits(10);
    print_digits(250);
    print_digits(12345);
    print_digits(100000);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Last Digit : 0
Digit: 1
Last Digit : 0
Digit: 2
Digit: 5
Last Digit : 0
Digit: 1
Digit: 2
Digit: 3
Digit: 4
Last Digit : 5
Digit: 1
Digit: 0
Digit: 0
Digit: 0
Digit: 0
Last Digit : 0
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use divisions, floats, or mathematical formulas such as pow if you want to avoid rounding errors.

Rather than reading a decimal number '`%d`', it's advisable to read a string '`%s`', and then parse the input data character by character.

Hence, your first digit becomes :

```
digit1 = s[0] - '0';
digit2 = s[1] - '0';
```

etc.

Don't forget to check for unauthorized entry, typically with a : `while (s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')`

Comment: This is a math problem. It should not be solved using strings. Also, divisons has nothing to do with the error, it's rather the floating-point return value of `pow()` which is to be avoided.

Comment: I have always been advised to avoid int to string casts.

Comment: @FreemanLambda As well as *conversions* - yes, that's reasonable. It's a bad piece of advice to tell someone to answer such a question by converting back and forth between strings and numbers.

Comment: @H2CO3 : how do you *know* this is math problem ?

Comment: @Cyan "I'm trying to make a program that takes an inputted **integer** and reads the digits forwards" (should I say this is a typical homework assignment about numeric operations?)

Comment: @FreemanLambda : under most circumstances, it's advisable to take input as string in production environment. This way, you are fully in charge of the parsing, avoiding nasty/unpredicted side effects when input is wrong.

Comment: @Cyan Yes, but here the point is to show one's ability to solve this problem using integer operations, for example. That doesn't mean you must use `scanf()`. You can still `fgets()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 : you seem to be very sure about what is the point of the question. Are you sharing the same classroom ?

Comment: @Cyan even if we agree that your string approach is safer in production environment, this question is a typical non-productive excercise, whose aim is practicing basic c instructions.

Comment: @Cyan No, I've just seen some hundreds of the very same kind of question on Stack Overflow already. It's obvious.

Comment: @H3CO3 You're making an assumption. However, it's probably safer to treat this like a math problem... as it's possible for bad TAs to share your opinion. I'd say the correct interpretation of the problem is that anything not explicitly specified is fair game. "takes an inputted integer" only means the user will enter an integer... it does not by itself specify the implementation of that data entry operation.